# Scale size of font icon when hovering over div, using only css?

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a div in which the size of a font icon scales when hovering over an entire div, not just the specific icon. Something similar to: http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/ To clarify, hovering over a `<li>` item causes a the specific icon to scale, but not the rest. I know how to cause it to change size upon mouseover of the icon itself, but I need it to scale when hovering over the rest of the div.

I'm wondering if this is possible to do simply through CSS, no jQuery/javascript, maybe through some selectors I don't know too well? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quickest example I could think of...

```
<h1><span>★</span>your text?</h1>
```

Something like this...

```
h1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 1rem;
    line-height: 1.8em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 1em; 
}

h1 span {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
   -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
     -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
        transition: all 0.3s ease-out;    
}
```

Think about it from right to left:

```
h1:hover h1 span {
    font-size: 3em;      
}
```

"any span within an h1 , while h1: is hovered over -> do this... "

## ROUND 2: this should spell it out.

HTML

```
<ul class="icon-list">
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="your-icon">&#9731;</div>
            Some text that doesn't move.
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.icon-list {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.icon-list li a {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    color: #111;
    -webkit-border-radius: 1em;
            border-radius: 1em;
}

.icon-list li a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,.1);
}

.icon-list li a .your-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}

.icon-list li a:hover .your-icon {
    font-size: 28px;
}
```

Comment: I tried a variation of that and it works pretty, the only problem is that when the icon enlarges, it pushes the other elements away.

Comment: That wasn't really your question. The last bit of code I offered *is* the answer to your question. If I have time, I'll make it for you.

Comment: Read this when you are ready to actually implement icon fonts: http://css-tricks.com/html-for-icon-font-usage/

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to scale when hovering over the div, you just use the hover selector on the div itself. Add a class to the div like `.font-hover` then in your css:

```
.font-hover:hover {
     font-size: 12px;
}
```

Obviously setting the font-size to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/cy33Z/)

**CSS**

```
div {
    padding: 3px 5px;
}
    div,span {
    transition: font-size .7s;
}

span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 45px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

div:hover span{
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div><span>OK,</span> Let's get bigger.</div>
```